# Association of a vector space to metric, normed and inner product spaces

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, vector-spaces, inner-products

There is a nice visual representation of mathematical spaces from [this post:](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133270/nested-boxes-of-different-thickness)

[image]

I am not quite sure how vector spaces fit into this image. I know metric space is not necessarily a vector spaces, but according to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space) an inner product is one:

> In linear algebra, an inner product space is a vector space with an additional structure called an inner product.

How would one draw a vector space in this image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any normed space is also a vector space. However, you do not need to define a norm on a vector space, meaning that all vector spaces are a union of the "normed space" rectangle and another rectangle that is outside the big "topological space" rectangle.